# Link same domain to AWS and DigitalOcean

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services

I want to link the same domain name to AWS and DigitalOcean.

Currently, `www.domain.com` is linked via Route53 to an S3 Bucket and I want `api.domain.com` to be linked to a droplet in DigitalOcean.

The problem is that DigitalOcean asks me to update the DNS records in my registrar panel. But I've just done it with AWS DNS servers.

So how can I do ? Am I missing something ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have both Route53 and DO as authoritative resolvers for your domain.

All you need to do, though is just create an `A` record for `api.domain.com` in R53, pointing to the IP address of your DO instance.

Answer (score 1):

Since api.domain.com is a subdomain and therefore different to domain.com you just need to have a separate A record for each pointing where you want. Don't think of this as pointing the same domain to two places because its not.